# how to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' for tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

My `tkinter` entry is returning `none`.

My main code is having this same issue so I decided to write a smaller code to test and I had the same issue:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a = Entry(root).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

b = Button(root,text = 'CLICK', command= lambda: test()).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

def test():
    print(a.get())


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `a` is somehow becoming inside `test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's entry.grid(...) return None

I think you want

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    a = Entry(root)
    a.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    b = Button(root,text = 'CLICK', command= lambda: test()).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    def test():
        print(a.get())


    root.mainloop()
```